# Get recent items function with Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

New to Doctrine. I'm trying to build a "list recent items function". It **should get all records newer than 3 months** but **if the result is less than 50 records it should get older ones until 50 is fetched**.

So if I have 100 records newer than three months I want to return all of them but nothing older. If I have 20 records from the last three months I want to return them and also the 30 most recent after that.

How would one do this with Doctrine? I don't want to make two queries (is it even called that?) if possible.

For now my EntityRepository just gets all records from the last three months as follows:

```
public function fetchRecent($from)
{
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->where($criteria->expr()->gte('created', $from));

    return $this->matching($criteria);
}
```

Comment: I don't see how to do this in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Hum, I read a bit too fast, you don't want to limit records if not older than three months. I don't see how to achieve this with a single query. (I'll think about it again but actually can't see..)

You could query the database to know how many recent records there are and then query the actual result.

```
public function fetchRecent($from, $nbRecords = 50)
{
    $count = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('COUNT(c.id)')
        ->andWhere('c.created >= :from')->setParameter('from', $from)
        ->addOrderBy('c.created', 'desc');
    $nbNewer = $count->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('q');
    if ($nbNewer<$nbRecords) {
        $query->setMaxResults($nbRecords);
    } else {
        $query->andWhere('q.created >= :from')->setParameter('from', $from);
    }
    $query->addOrderBy('q.created', 'desc');

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```